# How to access a variable value set inside Lua block in proxy pass

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, openresty

I am new to nginx.
I have a variable set  $myuser and updating the value ngx.var.myuser inside rewrite_by_lua. I want to pass this as a header in proxy_pass.
I am using proxy_add_header to add $myuser but I am not getting the updated value.

code block:

```
location /
{

 set $myuser '';

    rewrite_by_lua_block
    {
        local user=//code to get the updated value
       //perform some redirection logic on error
        ngx.var.myuser= user
       
       
    }
  
proxy_pass  "https://backend.com"
proxy_set_header  myheader  $myuser


}
```

value of $myuser is coming as empty but it's getting retrieved fine inside the lua block.

Comment: The directive is called [`proxy_set_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header), not `proxy_add_header`.

Comment: @un.def Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected the post. However, I am not getting the value. Right now, I am just trying with a return 302 "site?query="${variable}  , still it's not reflecting. I guess, the Lua block is getting executed after the regular nginx script? if so, what is the way I can do a proxy_pass to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked. No need to set variable anduse it in proxy_set_header. We can set the header inside the lua block

```
rewrite_by_lua_block
    {
        local user=//code to get the updated value
       //perform some redirection logic on error
       
         ngx.req.set_header("myheader", user)
       
       
    }
```